# java.lang.NullPointerException: Loading three charts (from github) into a 2x2 GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview, nullpointerexception

I am trying to make a 2x2 grid where the first 3 grids will have three(Thingspeak) charts imported from GitHub(https://github.com/MacroYau/ThingSpeakAndroid)and the fourth grid will have a live video recording of my camera(to be implemented later in a `WebView`).

I am using `GridView` to display the charts in a 2x2 grid but somehow the charts are not being positioned correctly as shown below:
[image]

TempHumidity.java:

```
package com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.demo;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.ThingSpeakChannel;
import com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.ThingSpeakLineChart;
import com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.ChannelFeed;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import lecho.lib.hellocharts.model.LineChartData;
import lecho.lib.hellocharts.model.Viewport;
import lecho.lib.hellocharts.view.LineChartView;
```

public class TempHumidity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private ThingSpeakChannel tsChannel, tsChannel1, tsChannel2;
private ThingSpeakLineChart tsChart, tsChart1, tsChart2;
private LineChartView chartView, chartView1, chartView2;

GridView simpleGrid;
int charts[] = {R.id.chart, R.id.chart1, R.id.chart2};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    simpleGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.simpleGridView); // init GridView
    // Create an object of CustomAdapter and set Adapter to GirdView
    GridViewAdapter customAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), charts);
    simpleGrid.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    // Connect to ThinkSpeak Channels
    tsChannel = new ThingSpeakChannel(377467);
    tsChannel1 = new ThingSpeakChannel(357670);
    tsChannel2 = new ThingSpeakChannel(377509);
    // Set listener for Channel feed update events
    tsChannel.setChannelFeedUpdateListener(new ThingSpeakChannel.ChannelFeedUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChannelFeedUpdated(long channelId, String channelName, ChannelFeed channelFeed) {
            // Show Channel ID and name on the Action Bar
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(channelName);
            getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Channel " + channelId);
            // Notify last update time of the Channel feed through a Toast message
            Date lastUpdate = channelFeed.getChannel().getUpdatedAt();
            Toast.makeText(TempHumidity.this, lastUpdate.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    // Fetch the specific Channel feed
    tsChannel.loadChannelFeed();

    // Create a Calendar object dated 1 minutes ago
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -1);

    // Configure LineChartView
    chartView = (LineChartView) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    chartView.setZoomEnabled(false);
    chartView.setValueSelectionEnabled(true);

    // Create a line chart from Field1 of ThinkSpeak Channel 9
    tsChart = new ThingSpeakLineChart(377467, 1);
    // Get 200 entries at maximum
    tsChart.setNumberOfEntries(200);
    // Set value axis labels on 10-unit interval
    tsChart.setValueAxisLabelInterval(10);
    // Set date axis labels on 5-minute interval
    tsChart.setDateAxisLabelInterval(1);
    // Show the line as a cubic spline
    tsChart.useSpline(true);
    // Set the line color
    tsChart.setLineColor(Color.parseColor("#D32F2F"));
    // Set the axis color
    tsChart.setAxisColor(Color.parseColor("#455a64"));
    // Set the starting date (5 minutes ago) for the default viewport of the chart
    tsChart.setChartStartDate(calendar.getTime());
    // Set listener for chart data update
    tsChart.setListener(new ThingSpeakLineChart.ChartDataUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChartDataUpdated(long channelId, int fieldId, String title, LineChartData lineChartData, Viewport maxViewport, Viewport initialViewport) {
            // Set chart data to the LineChartView
            chartView.setLineChartData(lineChartData);
            // Set scrolling bounds of the chart
            chartView.setMaximumViewport(maxViewport);
            // Set the initial chart bounds
            chartView.setCurrentViewport(initialViewport);
        }
    });
    // Load chart data asynchronously
    tsChart.loadChartData();



    //---------------end of Temp Humidity Channel---------------------//
    //---------------start of Soil Humidity Channel---------------------//

    tsChannel1.setChannelFeedUpdateListener(new ThingSpeakChannel.ChannelFeedUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChannelFeedUpdated(long channelId, String channelName, ChannelFeed channelFeed) {
            // Show Channel ID and name on the Action Bar
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(channelName);
            getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Channel " + channelId);
            // Notify last update time of the Channel feed through a Toast message
            Date lastUpdate = channelFeed.getChannel().getUpdatedAt();
            Toast.makeText(TempHumidity.this, lastUpdate.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    // Fetch the specific Channel feed
    tsChannel1.loadChannelFeed();

    // Create a Calendar object dated 1 minutes ago
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -1);

    // Configure LineChartView
    chartView1 = (LineChartView) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
    chartView1.setZoomEnabled(false);
    chartView1.setValueSelectionEnabled(true);

    // Create a line chart from Field1 of ThinkSpeak Channel 9
    tsChart1 = new ThingSpeakLineChart(377467, 1);
    // Get 200 entries at maximum
    tsChart1.setNumberOfEntries(200);
    // Set value axis labels on 10-unit interval
    tsChart1.setValueAxisLabelInterval(10);
    // Set date axis labels on 5-minute interval
    tsChart1.setDateAxisLabelInterval(1);
    // Show the line as a cubic spline
    tsChart1.useSpline(true);
    // Set the line color
    tsChart1.setLineColor(Color.parseColor("#D32F2F"));
    // Set the axis color
    tsChart1.setAxisColor(Color.parseColor("#455a64"));
    // Set the starting date (5 minutes ago) for the default viewport of the chart
    tsChart1.setChartStartDate(calendar.getTime());
    // Set listener for chart data update
    tsChart1.setListener(new ThingSpeakLineChart.ChartDataUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChartDataUpdated(long channelId, int fieldId, String title, LineChartData lineChartData, Viewport maxViewport, Viewport initialViewport) {
            // Set chart data to the LineChartView
            chartView1.setLineChartData(lineChartData);
            // Set scrolling bounds of the chart
            chartView1.setMaximumViewport(maxViewport);
            // Set the initial chart bounds
            chartView1.setCurrentViewport(initialViewport);
        }
    });
    // Load chart data asynchronously
    tsChart1.loadChartData()
  }
}
```

The above codes are for the 2 charts and the same codes have been duplicated for the third chart.

activity_main.xml

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="1dp">
<!--android:orientation="vertical">-->

<lecho.lib.hellocharts.view.LineChartView
    android:id="@+id/chart"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<lecho.lib.hellocharts.view.LineChartView
    android:id="@+id/chart1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    />
<lecho.lib.hellocharts.view.LineChartView
    android:id="@+id/chart2"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    />
```

gridVewAdapter.java

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

 private Context context;
 private final int[] charts;
 LayoutInflater inflter;

 public GridViewAdapter(Context Appcontext, int[] charts) {
    this.context = Appcontext;
    this.charts = charts;
    inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(Appcontext));
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null); // inflate the layout
    LineChartView cv = (LineChartView) view.findViewById(R.id.chart); // get the reference of ImageView
    return view;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return charts.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
```

}

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
<!--
-->
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/simpleGridView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:numColumns="2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I am getting the following error in the logcat:

```
01-14 17:11:24.784 23142-23142/com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.demo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.demo/com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.demo.TempHumidity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.demo.TempHumidity.onCreate(TempHumidity.java:60)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-14 17:11:28.007 23142-23146/com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.demo D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 587K, 19% free 8887K/10932K, paused 4ms+22ms, total 114ms
```

Below are the codes:

When I run the codes(as it is) without adding two charts in a Gridview, it works fine as shown below:
[image]

Comment: In the logcat, line 60 points to this line in the `TempHumidity.java` class: `chartView.setZoomEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a 2x2 grid you could also do it in a LinearLayout using layout_weight. When you statically specify each grid items width like you did above its possible to go out of bounds of the screen rather easily...

Replace the "object" element with your chart objects. Once again, this makes a 2x2 grid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Container LinearLayout -->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Row 1 -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <object
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <object
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Row 2 -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <object
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <object
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It fixed the layout issue by putting it in a 2x2 grid but it didn't fix the errors in the logcat.